# Drupal 7 - Blog Module - Adding title to single blog post

Tags: drupal-7, blogs

I have been asked to add a blog for a website built in Drupal 7. I activated the blog module and made a couple entries.

The postings show up fine on the blog page, but when I click through to a single entry it is just the text of the post. I would like to add the title to the page.

How is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have the title removed in page.tpl.php or you have a page--blog.tpl.php that has the title removed.

Copy your page.tpl.php and rename it to **page--blog.tpl.php** (**note there are two dashes between page and blog it will not work with just one**) and add in this snippet of PHP:

```
<h1 id="page-title"><?php print $title ?></h1>
```

Then clear Drupal's cache.  If this does not work out for you try adding it to **node--blog.tpl.php**.

Comment: Thanks... it is not used in the page.tpl.php and there is no page-blog.tpl.php. If I were to copy page.tpl.php to page-blog.tpl.php what would I need to add to the template to dipsplay the title?

Comment: This adds title for the first blog page, but it's still not working when you click into a single post. Any other ideas?

Comment: Then add it to your node--blog.tpl.php

Comment: no node--blog.tp.php currently, the node.tpl.php files does have the following.. 
 <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
      <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
    </h2>
  <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Do you have a link? If it's in the node.tpl.php then its likely that it's being hidden somewhere else.  Are the single blog nodes using panels?

Comment: I got it to work by adding an else to the conditional in my last comment and copying the file to node-blog.tp.php